# Make page public, then hide page from public based on settings. How?

Tags: php, seo, search-engine, public

I have user profiles on my site. Users can make it public by checking a checkbox (search able via a search engine) and uncheck the box to block the page from being searched on a search engine. Site is in php codeignitor.

How is this accomplished? I am esp lost on when the user unchecks the box to block the page from being public how is that done and how to do this in as real time as possible? A good example are the profiles on fb or linkedin.

Comment: FB and linked in just have block in front of the pages. Some are simply taken off the search listing. AFAIK these don't affect pages that have been cached before they were taken off the public list

Comment: what is you made non-public profiles only available to users who have logged it?

Comment: Removing pages from Google is *painful*. It took me a week to remove my homepage from Google, and that was after I submitted a deletion request, modified my `robots.txt`, and added a `<meta>` tag to every page on my site.

Comment: When you say block in front of pages, that means privacy settings? So it is the same logic then for how privacy levels are implemented i assume. if page has public privacy then google can crawl it. if privacy changes on the next bot visit the page is not found?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't secure, but you could check the referring URL of the visitors and allow/deny their requests by looking for a search engine's address. The results would still show up in Google, and there would be page caching (which you can kinda stop with a `<meta>` tag).

Basically, warn the users that when they make the page public, it's not that easy to make it private after that. I'd make it a tedious and painful process, as people will complain that "your site is brokeded".

Comment: Can you post an example? I haven't found a public FB profile yet... And Facebook is cruddy when it comes to Google: I made an application for FB and deleted it a year ago. Guess what's still showing up in Google results?

Comment: Apps are different. There is no privacy setting. But for user profiles there is a privacy setting of making your profile 'Public' or not. If yes then 2 things: Google can see it & any user can see the user's profile. When user unchecks it then Google cannot see it & NO user can see the user's profile except user's friends.

Comment: Google isn't a service like that. You can't tell them "I don't want you to hold my pages hostage." and expect instant results. It takes time for the crawler to re-crawl, and that can take weeks. I'd re-think your strategy a little, since there are *tons* of search engines to watch out for (Bing, Yahoo, etc.), so adding a checkbox to make users think that they can toggle privacy can make some frustrated when they find their page on Google the next day.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way to get pages automatically removed from google

- set a new last modified date of that specific page
- return an HTTP 410 for a page URL (you can still display content on it, or make the HTTP 410 google user agent specific, or no-cookie specific, or no language header specific)
- put the URL into a sitemap.xml (with the new last modified date)
- ping sitemap.xml to google

with this method you can make pages disappear from google SERPS in 1 to 2 hours (if your site gets crawled regularly).

note: if you want to kick out thousands and thousands of pages at once this process will take longer.